# Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ ($m > n$), can one always find an injective matrix $B$ close to $A$?

Tags: matrices, approximation

I'm looking for an approximation of a given matrix by an injective matrix close enough to the given matrix.

Suppose that $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is convex compact and a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $m > n$ is given.
For any $\epsilon > 0$, can one always find an injective matrix $B$ such that $\lVert (A-B)u \rVert < \epsilon$ for any $u \in U$ and $u_{1} \neq u_{2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $Bu_{1} \neq Bu_{2}$?

- Note that it is sufficient to show that such $B$ exists with $\lVert A - B \rVert < \epsilon$ (induced norm) as $\lVert(A-B) u\rVert \leq \lVert A-B \rVert \lVert u \rVert \leq \lVert A-B \rVert C$ for some $C >0$.

Comment: Do you know how to do the case $m=n$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for your consideration. I don't actually know for the case of $m=n$. Could you give me some insights if you know?

Comment: Sure, take $B= A+ t \begin{bmatrix} I \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Look at the SVD.

Comment: @copper.hat What if $A$ were $-t \begin{bmatrix} I \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$? Then $B=O$, which is not injective.

Comment: You need to do a little thinking. Choose $t$ small enough so the upper square part of $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your advice. I actually don't get it right now but will think about it.

Comment: If the upper square part of $A$ is non singular then $A$ is injective. You can perturb a singular square matrix by an arbitrarily small non zero amount to make it non singular.

Comment: @copper.hat I got it, thank you!

Comment: @copper.hat I was trying to extend this result but it seems not straightforward. If you are interested in it, please take a look at it :> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726285/can-one-find-an-injective-matrix-valued-approximation-of-a-given-matrix-valued-c